# Would you believe: I can't 'copy' the definition/value of a string item in the eclipse String Editor

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo). I have some very long string item definitions/values - e.g. over 1000 characters with a lot of embedded XML segments. The copy function works in the strings.xml tab where the XML characters are replaced by their multi-character equivalents but not the Resources tab. Whenever I select the definition/value text - either by using the cursor or using the shift-arrow keys, I do not activate the 'copy' or 'cut' commands.

Does anyone have the secret?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning i use to do everything on the resource tab , BUT then i started to have some problems that when i pasted the info it was not showing there, but it was being pasted on the resource node for some reason, so it make it my XML invalid.So i better started to do it on the XML tab, cause is faster also. So when you need to do something fast and pretty, you better do it on the XML tab, is less buggy.

**UPDATE:**

If your problem is just that you want the text with the values like '&#39' decoded. then you can just copy the text from the XML tab and go to **[this](http://coderstoolbox.net/string/)** site and entered there and click decode and you will get your decoded version of your text.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Eclipse do you have? I know some versions have been buggy for keyboard mapping and shortcuts.

Try looking at how those shortcuts are defined. See column "When" in Preferences > General > Keys ([image](http://www.rblab.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/pref_general_keys.jpg)).

Check if those shortcuts do not work for any editor (do they work for Java editor?). If they work for some editors, and not for another, then the problem might be that a plugin setting is causing them to perform another command. You could try disabling all unnecessary plugins.

**EDIT**:

I also found a [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=70077) on the Eclipse website that affected Eclipse 3.5.  It looks like the fix was to go to Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Typing, then uncheck "Update imports".

Comment: Thanks for the input, Kyle. Version is 3.7 I tried the bug fix but no improvement. Still can't activate the Ctrl+C or Ctrl+X commands on the Edit menu.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure what OS you're running, but you could look into that. Maybe a system shortcut that's interfering? Does copy and paste work with other applications?

Comment: OS is W7 and Copy & Paste work flawlessly everywhere else, including in the strings.xml tab in eclipse(?) - just not in the structured strings editor page.

Comment: On second thought, I've never tried copying from there. Why not just copy from the strings.xml file?